# Characters with only horizontal 横 strokes

Tags: characters

Aside from 一, 二 and 三 are there any other characters made from only horizontal 横 strokes?

Comment: Rest assured, those are the only three AFAIK

Comment: I believe no. Characters made of vertical strokes is only 川

Comment: @Sylvia Thanks Sylvia. I don't think 川 has three vertical strokes though. It's 撇竖竖 if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: @Kantura Right, in that case, there is no. btw, it's 竖撇 竖 竖：）

Comment: @Sylvia I've never seen it called a 竖撇. I've only ever seen it called 撇. I can see where you're coming from though. But if you're going to add a bit of nuance to the kind of 撇 then why not do the same to the kinds of 竖. i.e. 竖撇 中竖 长竖 :)  Reference 1     https://bihua.51240.com/e5b79d__bihuachaxun/    Reference 2     https://baike.baidu.com/item/丿/6436512

Comment: @Kantura okay, i learnt it is 竖撇，because it is different from 撇 in e.g. "千"

Comment: @Kantura You can refer to this site: http://www.hwjyw.com/zyzx/jxsc/hy/200912/t20091204_34269.shtml You're not wrong, but 撇 is a broader scope. When I learnt Chinese in school as a kid, I learnt 竖撇.

Comment: @Sylvia Yeah, I agree fully with you. There are many variations of 撇 (and many variations of all the other strokes), for example in 八 几 只 这 手 首 etc. They all have different forms of 撇. And understandably there must be a way to distinguish them. For example 竖撇 would of course be in 川 as you pointed out.

Comment: No.
Maybe there is another word made from only horizontal,but no one use it,only exists in dictionary

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**[亖](http://zisea.com/zscontent.asp?uni=4E96)** there is, also, this alternative character for 四.

---

is an alternative form of 上.

is an alternative form of 下.

is an alternative form of 二 (and also apparently the Japanese Ditto mark).

Comment: All four characters you’ve listed are the *original forms* of the words they represent.

Comment: OP was asking specifically for characters, not words.

Comment: Uh. Sometimes characters and words are interchangeable?

Comment: @JohnFrazer If you were directing that comment at me, it is crucial to distinguish between words or morphemes and the *representation* of words or morphemes. Without a clear separation of this, one cannot hope to talk about character history properly. For example, characters can change while the morphemes/words they represent remains the same.

Answer (score 2):

It's probably not what the OP has in mind, but I'm going to give this as an answer (since the question wasn't limited to a particular writing style).

> ## ☰，☳，☵，☶，☷，☴，☲，☱

These are the eight ancient Chinese [八卦](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E5%85%AB%E5%8D%A6/166475) ([Bagua](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bagua)), also known as trigrams.

Going further, we have the [King Wen sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/King_Wen_sequence) (文王卦序):

> ## ䷀䷁䷂䷃䷄䷅䷆䷇䷈䷉䷊䷋䷌䷍䷎䷏䷐䷑䷒䷓䷔䷕䷖䷗䷘䷙䷚䷛䷜䷝䷞䷟䷠䷡䷢䷣䷤䷥䷦䷧䷨䷩䷪䷫䷬䷭䷮䷯䷰䷱䷲䷳䷴䷵䷶䷷䷸䷹䷺䷻䷼䷽䷾䷿